# A strange behaviour with function $\,_2F_1$

Tags: special-functions

I posted today a question on MSE [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439605/approximation-of-int-0-pi-bigx-pi-x-csc-x-bigk-dx-quad-forall-k?noredirect=1#comment9294632_4439605)

```
  u=(5*(49*Pi^2*Zeta[3] - 558*Zeta[5]))/(77*Pi^2*Zeta[3] - 930*Zeta[5])
  f[k_]:= Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -k, 3/2, u]
```

Computing

```
  N[f[10]] =-8.29107
  N[f[10.]]=+3.02495
```

The second one is correct.

Could any one accept to make me understanging what is going wrong ?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

After comments and answer, if I rationalize

```
 u=-137172947796693/512328299943181
```

the problem disappears.

Thanks, everybody !

Comment: Or you can change the order of evaluation, e.g., `Total@N[List @@ (f[10] // Apart)]` evaluates to `3.02495`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like numerical instability due to cancellations among terms in `f[10]` with the *machine precision*. If you specify the precision that you want to obtain, then it gives the correct answer.

```
N[f[10], 40]  (* 3.024945718826484765909050369309114702577 *)
```

**Details**: the sum in the numerator `Numerator[f[10]] / 1835008` has 11 terms. You can see them by

```
List @@ (Numerator[f[10]] / 1835008)
```

or their numerical values with the *machine precision*:

```
N[List @@ (Numerator[f[10]] / 1835008)]
```

Summing up them gives a wrong result:

```
Plus @@ N[List @@ (Numerator[f[10]] / 1835008)]  (* -7.20576*^16 *)
```

From the following experiments, it seems that you need 19 digits or more to get the first digit correctly:

```
Table[{n,Plus @@ N[List @@ (Numerator[f[10]] / 1835008), n]},{n,16, 22}]
```

```
{{16,0``-17.31500855618509},{17,0.*^16},{18,3.*^16},{19,2.6*^16},{20,2.63*^16},{21,2.629*^16},{22,2.6290*^16}}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is, sadly, simple round-off error. (I was hoping to learn something more interesting.)

Lets look at `f[10]`:

```
f10 = f[10]
(*    
  (1835008 (43551160253105097901 π^20 Zeta[3]^10 -
     4808402859534428003850 π^18 Zeta[3]^9 Zeta[5] +
     238905994054787308522350 π^16 Zeta[3]^8 Zeta[5]^2 -
     7034330305341815976769500 π^14 Zeta[3]^7 Zeta[5]^3 +
     135925793707604259244173750 π^12 Zeta[3]^6 Zeta[5]^4 -
     1801105572337397766462487500 π^10 Zeta[3]^5 Zeta[5]^5 +
     16574098514883746872868437500 π^8 Zeta[3]^4 Zeta[5]^6 -
     104587763224772152070746875000 π^6 Zeta[3]^3 Zeta[5]^7 +
     433131075279238064824511718750 π^4 Zeta[3]^2 Zeta[5]^8 -
     1063000622677773009307148437500 π^2 Zeta[3] Zeta[5]^9 +
     1174035206087269790337070312500 Zeta[5]^10)) /
  (138567 (77 π^2 Zeta[3] - 930 Zeta[5])^10)
*)
```

The terms being added/subtracted in the numerator and denominator are quite large:

```
{nf, df} = N@N[NumeratorDenominator[f10], $MachinePrecision]; 
terms1 = Numerator@f10 /. Plus -> List // N
terms2 = Denominator@f10 /. Plus -> List // N

(*
  {4.41454*10^36, -4.26001*10^37, 1.84995*10^38, -4.7608*10^38, 
   8.04049*10^38, -9.31201*10^38, 7.48959*10^38, -4.13079*10^38, 
   1.49518*10^38, -3.20725*10^37, 3.09602*10^36}
  {5.60809*10^34, 9.63772*10^34}
*)
```

The expected round-off error is approximately:

```
1/df^2 (df*Abs@Max[terms1*$MachineEpsilon/2] Sqrt@Length@terms1 + 
   nf*Abs@Max[terms2*$MachineEpsilon/2] Sqrt@Length@terms2)
(*  18.5673  *)
```

Since `f[10]` is exact, one can use the adaptive-precision capability of `N[]` to compute an accurate value by giving it a numeric target precision in its second argument.  For instance, we can use `$MachinePrecision`, which is `15.95...` (but not the symbol `MachinePrecision`, which represents machine precision, the default target precision of `N[expr]`):

```
N@N[f10, $MachinePrecision]
(*  3.02495  *)
```

With `f[10.]` the internal code does not make the polynomial expansion, but goes straight to the numerical routine for calculating ${}_2F_1$.